# jQuery - Uncaught Type Error: t.append is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am currently working on a form submission using jQuery Validate & Ajax. When I submit this, nothing happens and the page reloads - because .append() is not a function for some reason?

Code below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var $contact_form = $('#enquiry-form');
$contact_form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
    submitHandler: function($contact_form) {
        $contact_form.append('<img class="loading" src="../../images/site/loading.gif">');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../ajax/contact-form-send.php",
            data: $contact_form.serialize(),
            success: function(response) {

                var resp = JSON.parse(response);

                $contact_form.find('input').remove();
                $contact_form.find('textarea').remove();
                $contact_form.append('<p class="status-code ' + resp.status + '">' + resp.msg + '</p>');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Ajax request not received');
            }
        });

        return false; //Stop the redirect after submission via ajax.
    }
});
```

Comment: You are redefining `$contact_form` as submitHandler parameter which then is the DOM node, not jq object

Comment: Right, okay. Sorry, I'm unsure what I need to change exactly?

Comment: Well, you could just remove it: `submitHandler: function() {...}`

Comment: Event handlers receive the `event` as the first parameter. Just remove `$submit_form` from the `submitHandler: function($submit_form)` line because this variable will be the event or jqEvent.

Comment: Right, gotcha. Thanks a lot guys - That seemed to work!

Comment: @marekful From [DOC](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), it would be the DOM node form

Answer (score 0):

The developer provides an argument for the submitHandler function that represents the form object. `submitHandler: function(form) {...` so then you can use it like this...`data: $(form).serialize()`, etc.

```
var $contact_form = $('#enquiry-form');
$contact_form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        $contact_form.append('<img class="loading" src="../../images/site/loading.gif">');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../ajax/contact-form-send.php",
            data: $contact_form.serialize(),
            success: function(response) {

                var resp = JSON.parse(response);

                $contact_form.find('input').remove();
                $contact_form.find('textarea').remove();
                $contact_form.append('<p class="status-code ' + resp.status + '">' + resp.msg + '</p>');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Ajax request not received');
            }
        });

        return false; //Stop the redirect after submission via ajax.
    }
});
```

Comment: More correctly... the developer provides an argument for the submitHandler function that represents the form object.  `submitHandler: function(form) {...` so then you can use it like this...`data: $(form).serialize()`, etc.

Comment: If you're going to plagiarize my comment into your answer, at least take the time to edit your own code block to show what it's saying.